# How to call uninstall.php?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am a newbie in WordPress... I have created my plugin... now i am creating uninstall.php file for uninstall my plugin...

this is my code of uninstall.php

```
if(!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN'))
  exit ();

 //here I am dropping my table and options...
```

I don't know how to call uninstall.php? from where to call? from where i can uninstall my plugin...

I know register_uninstall_hook() but when it get triggered?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall hook and `uninstall.php` file are two alternate ways to implement uninstall functionality, they are independent of each other.

When [`uninstall_plugin()`](http://queryposts.com/function/uninstall_plugin/) is called it checks for `uninstall.php` **or** hook (in this order).

So if you are using file approach there is nothing special you need to do to call it. WordPress looks it's up by name and runs on uninstall natively.

Comment: Thanks... one more question from where i can uninstall my plugin?

Comment: does delete and uninstall both are same?

Comment: @user41362 I don't follow what exactly you mean by "where" there.

Comment: i don't know how to uninstall plugin? i mean from which place i can uninstall it?

Comment: @user41362 using WordPress admin? Delet and uninstall are synonyms if you are confused about that there. Deactivate is different.